# Getting Assemble script failed error building application in Redhat Openshift

Tags: openshift, redhat

I'm new to Redhat `OpenShift` and trying to deploy node application (with angularjs + mysql) and running into build issues.

Using `openshift` console created node application and in advanced options pointed to the private repository and linked configured secret (ssh key to private repository).

My build is failing with `"Assemble script failed"`. Pasting the logs as below (from console - obfuscated private keys and values).

Not sure if I'm missing some configurations. Appreciate help on this.

```
Cloning "ssh://username@bitbucket.org/username/my-app.git" ...
Commit: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Fixed readme)
Author: Name <email>
Date:   Wed Sep 6 19:50:59 2017 -0700
Pulling image "docker- 
registry.default.svc:5000/openshift/nodejs@sha256:0000000000000" ...
---> Installing application source
---> Building your Node application from source
Current git config
url.https://github.com.insteadof=git@github.com: 
url.https://.insteadof=ssh:// 
url.https://github.com.insteadof=ssh://git@github.com 
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=ssh://username@bitbucket.org/username/my-app.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
---> Installing dependencies
---> Using 'npm install -s --only=production' 
error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from docker- 
registry.default.svc:5000/openshift/nodejs@sha256:0000000000000
```

Pls note that my source code is hosted on private repository and per log above it appears openshift is able to access the repository and download the source code.

Comment: Run ``oc get events``, or look at events under monitoring in the web console and see if the build pod was killed due to running out of memory. When installing packages with ``npm`` it can use excessive amounts of memory, more than the 512Mi default. If this looks to be the problem run ``oc patch bc/yourappname --patch '{"spec":{"resources":{"limits":{"memory":"1Gi"}}}}'`` and then trigger a new build.

Comment: Thanks Graham - really appreciate your inputs. 
`oc get events` is not returning anything also checked under monitoring in the web console there are no events listed.
Tried to apply the memory patch but the command is failing. Pls note that I'm running oc on windows
`oc patch bc/myapp --patch '{"spec": 
   {"resources":{"limits":{"memory":"1Gi"}}}}'`
`Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Graham for the pointer. I recreated the application and this time in advanced options on the web console selected 1 GB (from default of 500 mb) after which my build worked fine.